# How can I use Ubuntu 18.04 for monitoring LAN traffic via bridged interfaces?

Tags: 18.04, network-bridge

Can I use Ubuntu 18.04 on the 2 NICs server for monitoring LAN traffic?

```
[gw]-----[eth0][Server][eth1]------[switch]---[clients]
```

How can I set this up?

Answer (score 3):

Ettercap should do exactly what you want:

```
sudo apt install ettercap-graphical
```

And then run it as root:

```
sudo ettercap -G
```

And under the sniff menu, select bridged sniffing. This will pop up a window with drop-down boxes. Select your two network interfaces. This will start bridged sniffing if your sniffer, useful for a box that is in between router and modem.

More info:

- [Ettercap Tutorial For Network Sniffing and Man In The Middle](https://www.poftut.com/ettercap-tutorial-network-sniffing-man-middle/)
- [Ettercap ManPage](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-ettercap/)

You can also look into other applications like tcpdump and wireshark:

```
sudo apt install wireshark tcpdump
```

And you can learn how to use them with the manpages:

```
man wireshark
man tcpdump
man ettercap
```

Comment: Thank you
and How to setup interfaces?